# Parameters and PowerShell functions

Tags: powershell

I'm definitely not getting something here:

I'm creating a simple function to replicate a string x times.  I am having some weird problem with the parameter -- it doesn't seem to be recognizing the second parameter.
When I run the function, it returns an empty string. Further, I think it's lumping the 2 parameters into 1. Here's my code:

```
Function Repeat-String([string]$str, [int]$repeat) {
  $builder = new-object System.Text.StringBuilder
  for ($i = 0; $i -lt $repeat; $i++) {[void]$builder.Append($str)}
  $builder.ToString()
}
```

First I dot-source it to load it:

`. .\RepeatString.ps1`

And then I execute it like this:

`Repeat-string("x", 7)`
I expected a string of 7 x's. I got an empty string.

I went poking around some more, and I changed the "for" loop.  I replaced the "-lt $repeat" part with "-lt 5", so that I would get a fixed number of repeats.  When I did that, I got the following output (without the quotes):

Repeat-String("x", 7)

"x 7x 7x 7x 7x 7"

It looks as though it is concatenating the $str and $repeat parameters instead of treating them like 2 separate parameters. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is that you need to convert your code to the following

```
Repeat-string "x" 7
```

In PowerShell, any time you put a group of values inside ()'s, you are creating an array. This means in your sample you're actually passing an array to the function as a single parameter.

Comment: Thanks!  I knew I was doing something stupid -- just wasn't sure what.

Comment: @JMarsch, everyone gets tripped up by this at least once.  It's really annoying :(

Answer (score 7):

Here's a better way, just multiply your (any) string by N repeats:

```
PS > function Repeat-String([string]$str, [int]$repeat) {  $str * $repeat }
PS > Repeat-String x 7
xxxxxxx

PS > Repeat-String JMarsch 3
JMarschJMarschJMarsch
```

Comment: Every new thing I learn about powershell just shows me how cool it is.  Thanks for sharing that, Shay +1

Comment: In a way, Shay Levy's comment shows that we could just use the "multiply string" feature **instead** of writing a user-defined-function.

Answer (score 6):

A noted Chinese proverb states:

> *"Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish
>   and you feed him for a lifetime."*

For the cosmopolitan-minded among you, the original is `授人以魚不如授人以漁`
and the Pinyin romanization is `Shòu rén yǐ yú bùrú shòu rén yǐ yú`. 
(I have been learning to speak a smattering of Mandarin and to write Pinyin so I have to practice! Curiously I found the above Pinyin expression seemed to be an enigma, but that is a story for another time...:-)

**Now to my point:** JMarsch came upon a common PowerShell pitfall liable to trip up anyone used to "conventional" languages, and @JaredPar provided the correct resolution. I submit, though, that answer is akin to slapping down a fish in front of you!

Just published on Simple-Talk.com, [Down the Rabbit Hole: A Study in PowerShell Pipelines, Functions, and Parameters](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/down-the-rabbit-hole--a-study-in-powershell-pipelines,-functions,-and-parameters/) discusses the above pitfall along with many other nuances of the function-calling interface. One section of my article, for example, covers the subtle differences between all of the following calls to function **f**, most of which will *not* yield what you expect.

```
f(1,2,3)
f (1,2,3)
f 1,2,3
f (1 2 3)
f 1 2 3
```

Look for the PDF download of the handy wallchart reference accompanying the article, too.

Here's a thumbnail:
[image: PowerShell Functions Quick Reference]

(Oh, and you may want to also check out the list of humorous spin-offs of the above classic quote at [Give a man a fish...](http://www.amatecon.com/fish.html))

Comment: What does the fish have to do with it?  :)

Answer (score 0):

Of course JaredPar is right.

I like to use the built in range function `..` for this too: (notice I start at 1 instead of 0)

```
Function Repeat-String([string]$str, [int]$repeat) {
  $builder = new-object System.Text.StringBuilder
  1..$repeat | %{ [void]$builder.Append($str) }
  return $builder.ToString()
}

Repeat-string "x" 7
```

Comment: Thanks -- didn't know about the range function.  I'm going to have to fit a book on powershell into my reading list.  (I guess at this point, I might as well look/wait for a powershell 2.0 book)